# Как анимировать Skeleton Screen с помощью маски CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animation

Я пытаюсь добавить тонкую анимацию мерцания к skeleton, похожему [на этот](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/shimmer). В настоящее время у меня есть код, который выглядит следующим образом (см. На [CodePen](https://codepen.io/muhammadrehansaeed/pen/KKzBedY))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытаюсь написать скелетный компонент, который может принимать SVG следующим образом:

```
<div class="skeleton" aria-busy="true">
  <svg width="233" height="68" viewBox="0 0 233 68" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g opacity="0.8">
      <rect x="79" y="32" width="154" height="11" rx="2" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.07"/>
      <rect width="179" height="20" rx="2" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.07"/> 
      <rect x="79" y="52" width="84" height="11" rx="2" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.07"/>
      <rect y="26" width="67" height="42" rx="2" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.07"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Вот CSS, который я использую для анимации мерцания над SVG:

```
.skeleton {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.skeleton::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(243, 242, 241) 0%, rgb(237, 235, 233) 50%, rgb(243, 242, 241) 100%) 0px 0px / 90% 100% no-repeat rgb(243, 242, 241);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  
  animation-name: skeleton-animation;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes skeleton-animation {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

Я пытаюсь понять, как использовать  маску, как описано [здесь](https://github.com/microsoft/fast/pull/3770#issuecomment-685942763), чтобы мерцание анимации происходило только над SVG.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to Animate a Skeleton Screen with a CSS Mask](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63914191/7394871) от участника  [@Muhammad Rehan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1212017/muhammad-rehan-saeed).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/63914191/7394871

Answer (score 6):

Один из способов использовать SVG в качестве изображения-маски и позволить обновлять положение фона линейного градиента.

```css
.skeleton {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 233px;
  height: 68px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(143, 142, 141) 0%, rgb(237, 235, 233) 50%, rgb(143, 142, 141) 100%) 0px 0px / 100% 100% rgb(243, 242, 241);
  -webkit-mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
  margin: 1em;
  animation: linearAnim 2s infinite linear
}

@keyframes linearAnim {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 230px 0px;
  }
}

/* demo purpose only */
.skeleton + .skeleton {

  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(143, 142, 141,0.75) 0%, rgba(237, 235, 233, 0.75) 50%, rgba(143, 142, 141, 0.75) 100%) 0px 0px / 100% 100% rgba(243, 242, 241, 0.5);
  }
  .skeleton.blue {
  background-color:blue;
  }
  .skeleton.red {
  background-color:red;
  }
  .skeleton.yellow {
  background-color:yellow;
  }
  .skeleton.green {
  background-color:green;
  }
  .flex {display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;box-sizing:border-box;padding-top:0.6em;font-size:10px;color:#fff8;}
body {background:#bee; display:grid;grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill, 300px);}
```

```html
<div class="skeleton" aria-busy="true"></div>
<div class="skeleton blue" aria-busy="true"></div>
<div class="skeleton red" aria-busy="true"></div>
<div class="skeleton yellow" aria-busy="true"></div>
<div class="skeleton green flex" aria-busy="true">On its way ...</div>
```

[вот аналогичный вопрос с другим методом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457612/css-animation-only-render-overlay-on-specific-elements/56460124)

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63916580/7394871) от участника  [@G-Cyrillus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442099/g-cyrillus).</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Если не нужно использовать SVG, то это будет немного проще в HTML.

Но вот как это сделать с SVG.

```css
.shimmer-rect {
  animation-name: skeleton-animation;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes skeleton-animation {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(2000px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="skeleton" aria-busy="true">
  <svg width="233" height="68" viewBox="0 0 233 68" overflow="visible">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="shimmer" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x2="2000" spreadMethod="repeat">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="rgb(237,235,233)"/>
        <stop offset="25%" stop-color="rgb(243,242,241)"/>
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="rgb(237,235,233)"/>
      </linearGradient>
      <mask id="shimmer-mask">
        <rect x="79" y="32" width="154" height="11" rx="2" fill="white"/>
        <rect width="179" height="20" rx="2" fill="white"/> 
        <rect x="79" y="52" width="84" height="11" rx="2" fill="white"/>
        <rect y="26" width="67" height="42" rx="2" fill="white"/>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <g mask="url(#shimmer-mask)">
      <rect class="shimmer-rect" x="-2000" width="3000" height="100%" fill="url(#shimmer)"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63919294/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>